# Trying to work out how to have the client (browser) send the jwt token back so I can verify

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I can set the JWT token in the header using either res.header('token', token). I can see it in the response header in the browser. but I'm trying to work out how to have the browser send the token so I can verify it?

I have tried setting the header to include the token, I have tried looking online but everyone seems to test only with postman and entering the header in the get request. I have tested it here and it works fine.

setting the token:

```
res.header('token', user.token).redirect('/users/home')
```

verifying the token:

```
jwt.verify(req.header('token'), config.token, (err, authData) => {
    if(err) {
      res.sendStatus(403);
    } else {
      res.json({
        message: 'access granted',
        authData
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: You are right Jethro, you can set the token in the request headers (made by the client) or also you can set the jwt in a cookie in the server response and then every request that you send from client to server will include that cookie, in which case you need to set up your server to extract the JWT from the request cookie.

How were you setting your JWT in your client requests headers? It should work ;)

Comment: Wait, do you have an independent client app? or is your client app built on top of Express too? I ask because I see you have a redirect: `res.header('token', user.token).redirect('/users/home')`.

Usually, JWT is used to protect APIs, so instead of a redirection, the server returns the JWT in a JSON formatted response (or similar) to the client; which then stores the JWT somewhere (localstorage or cookie) and includes it in every request made to the API.

Comment: @Davo Hi, the redirection points to a protected route where im running the verify function. that seems to make sense that its working in postman requests. How can i access a jwt in either localstorage or a cookie? yes the app is built on top of express, is there a better way to send a response to the client after logging in or should i just render a page with the success or failure message?